# 2-D Fourier Transform of complex exponential with 2-D quadratic phase

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, signal-processing

I've been looking around to see if there is either an exact transform pair or an approximation to either of the following but have not been able to find anything:

$$
\mathcal{F}_{xy}\left( e^{i\cdot(a x^2 + bxy + cy^2)} \right)
=
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} {
  \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} {
e^{i\cdot(a x^2 + bxy + cy^2)}
e^{-ik_x x} e^{-ik_y y} \,
\mathrm{d}x \,
\mathrm{d}y
}
}
$$

$$
\bar {\mathcal{F} }_{xy}\left( e^{i\cdot(a x^2 + bxy + cy^2)} \right)
=
\int_{-T_y / 2}^{+T_y / 2} {
  \int_{-T_x / 2}^{+T_x / 2} {
e^{i\cdot(a x^2 + bxy + cy^2)}
e^{-ik_x x} e^{-ik_y y} \,
\mathrm{d}x \,
\mathrm{d}y
}
}
$$

I know the 1-D case for the infinite case $\mathcal{F}_{x}(e^{i\cdot ax^2})$ can be worked out, as can the finite case $\bar{\mathcal{F}}_{x}(e^{i\cdot ax^2})$ using Fresnel integrals, but neither strategy works with the cross term of $bxy$ in the phase.

Any ideas or pointers to existing work would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $a \ne 0$, write $ax^{2}+bxy+cy^{2}=a(x+by/2a)^{2}+(c-b^{2}/4a)y^{2}$. Make the substitution $x=x'-by/2a$ in the double-integral to obtain
$$
    \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{i(ax^{2}+bxy+cy^{2})}e^{-ik_{x}x}e^{-ik_{y}y}\,dxdy\\
   = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{iax\,'\,^{2}+i(c-b^{2}/4a)y^{2}}e^{-ik_{x}x\,'}e^{-i(k_{y}-bk_{x}/2a)y}\,dy.
$$
There are convergence/interpretation issues that I have ignored, but no worse that the integrals you can already evaluate. And, I suspect this is what you want. Check the details: I am likely to make mistakes in Algebra, but it should be straightforward to fix any error.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to work this out in the next day or two and will let you know.